# Issue with script not saving new lines or counting file size

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I'm noticing an issue with my script here. The big issue here comes from my fprintf not saving the newlines to a file correctly. For example, there should be 47 new lines saved when I use a specific test file. I've tried the find command by itself and piped it to wc -l to get the number. However, when I try and save to a file (saving a new line for each result and try to count that), I only get 35. What's stranger to me, is that when I swap around the order of the file extensions (searching for gif first for example) it also messes with the new lines saved (doing gif first saves 3 new lines). So I'm not sure what the deal is there.

Another issue I'm having is printing out the correct file size. For example, in one of the test files I use, my total file size comes out to 2,908,160 when it should be 2,628,419.

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Godfried Weihs
#Lab 2 - Search and Report
#CS 3030 - Scripting

#If Statement checks for usage, prints appropriate message if path is empty
#+ else it runs through the scripts normally

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo Usage: srpt path
    exit 1
else
    echo -e "SearchReport $HOSTNAME $(basename "$1") $(date)\n"

    #Finds all required files and saves them to temporary files to be used for count output
    find $1 -mindepth 1 \
    \( -type d -fprintf /tmp/dcnt "\n" \) , \
    \( -type f -fprintf /tmp/fcnt "\n" \) , \
    \( -type l -fprintf /tmp/scnt "\n" \) , \
    \( -type f -mtime +365 -fprintf /tmp/ocnt "\n" \) , \
    \( -type f -size +500000c -fprintf /tmp/lcnt "\n" \) , \
    \( -type f -name *.jpg -o -name *.bmp -o -name *.gif -fprintf /tmp/gcnt "\n" \) , \
    \( -type f -name '*.o' -fprintf /tmp/tcnt "\n" \) , \
    \( -type f -executable -fprintf /tmp/ecnt "\n" \) , \
    \( -type f -fprintf /tmp/total "$(du -ch -B1 $1)" \)

    #Print out results saved in tmp folder
    echo Execution time $SECONDS
    printf "Directories %'d\n"  $(cat /tmp/dcnt | wc -l)
    printf "Files %'d\n" $(cat /tmp/fcnt | wc -l)
    printf "Sym links %'d\n" $(cat /tmp/scnt | wc -l)
    printf "Old files %'d\n" $(cat /tmp/ocnt | wc -l)
    printf "Large files %'d\n" $(cat /tmp/lcnt | wc -l)
    printf "Graphics files %'d\n" $(cat /tmp/gcnt | wc -l)
    printf "Temporary files %'d\n" $(cat /tmp/tcnt | wc -l)
    printf "Executable files %'d\n" $(cat /tmp/ecnt | wc -l)
    #printf "Total file size %'d\n" $(du -hs -B1 $1 | cut f -1)     
    #printf "Total file size %'d\n" $(du -ch -B1 $1 | tail -n1 | cut -f 1)
    printf "Total file size %'d\n" $(cat /tmp/total | tail -n1 | cut -f 1)

fi
```

I feel like there are a couple of minor things I'm just not seeing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which `-fprintf` isn't working correctly, all of them?

Comment: no, just the one searching for image file extensions I assume. I don't know if it's the find command itself or what exactly.

Comment: You need to quote the arguments containing wildcards, otherwise they'll be expanded by the shell, not passed literally to the `find` command.

Comment: The granularity of `du` is disk blocks, not bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Quote the arguments with the image file extensions, otherwise the wildcard will be expanded by the shell rather than being passed to `find` (unless there are no matching files in the current directory). Also, you need to group them all together with parentheses, because `-o` has lower precedence than the implied `-a` that combines adjacent expressions; that's why the order of the extensions mattered, you were only running `-fprintf` for the last expression.

```
\( -type f \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.bmp' -o -name '*.gif' \) -fprintf /tmp/gcnt "\n" \) , \
```

Regarding the total file size, `du` gets each file's size in disk blocks, not the file length in bytes. So the reported total will be larger than the total lengths of all the files because they're all rounded up to the next block size.

Comment: That certainly took care of the image line, so thank you for that. As far as summing up the total file size (which needs to be in bytes) what's the best approach? Just about everywhere I looked was saying to use du